# Help with vector cross product identity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus, vectors, geometry

In EM Physics we were given the problem to show that

$$\vec a \times (\vec b \times \vec c) = \vec b (\vec a\cdot \vec c) - \vec c (\vec a \cdot \vec b).$$

I know first

$$ \vec a \times (\vec b \times \vec c) = \hat e_i \epsilon_{ijk} a_j (\epsilon_{kmn} b_m c_n )$$

but don't know where to go from here. I don’t want to fully expand. If someone can give me pointer that would be great.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home to this question?

Comment: Duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352846/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use properties of the  Levi-Civita tensor, specifically

$$\epsilon_{kij}\epsilon_{kmn} = \delta_{im}\delta_{jn} - \delta_{in}\delta_{jm}$$

so that

\begin{align} 
\vec a \times (\vec b \times \vec c) &= \hat e_i \epsilon_{ijk} a_j (\epsilon_{kmn} b_m c_n )&\\
& = \hat e_i ( \delta_{im}\delta_{jn} - \delta_{in}\delta_{jm} )a_j b_m c_n &\\
&= \hat e_i \delta_{im}\delta_{jn} a_j b_m c_n -  \hat e_i \delta_{in}\delta_{jm} a_j b_m c_n &\\
&= \hat e_i a_j b_i c_j - \hat e_i a_j b_j c_i \\
&=\vec b (\vec a\cdot \vec c) - \vec c(\vec a\cdot\vec b)
\end{align}

Any steps in between should be straight forward. You may want to double check these indices are in the correct spot. See the link in the answer provided by Puk.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Levi-Civita symbol is standard knowledge on undergraduate physics courses.  Also, it's actually a tensor density, and not a tensor (it doesn't transform as a tensor).

Comment: @Tom It probably depends on the university. It was part of my undergraduate course in Germany, first year even.

Comment: OK yes it probably depends.  Now that I think about it I probably did actually learn it on my electromagnetism course I took, so maybe depends on the university.

Comment: The Levi-Civita symbol can be interpreted as an orientation tensor which does transform as a tensor, it just has negative components in “left-handed” choices of basis. I would just share that my mnemonic is basically to look at $\epsilon_{abc}\epsilon_{ak\ell}$ and say “well these are zero for non-permutations so $abc$ and $ak\ell$ are both permutations, either they are the same permutation giving +1, or they are opposite, giving -1. They are the same if $b=k$ and $c=\ell$ so that's $\delta_{bk}\delta_{c\ell},$ they are opposite if $b=\ell$ and $c=k$ so that's $-\delta_{b\ell}\delta_{ck}.$”

Answer (score 12):

I always have trouble with this identity, so here's a fun way to derive it in three-dimensions. It may be argued that this method is a little convoluted, but I find it much easier to remember than the Levi-Civita contraction formula, and much less tedious than working out the components! Let's call the vector $\mathbf{a \times (b \times c) = d}$, and see what we can say about $\mathbf{d}$, using our intuition.

Now, $\mathbf{d}$ must be perpendicular to $\mathbf{a}$ by the definition of the cross-product. Furthermore, $\mathbf{d}$ must also be perpendicular to the vector $\mathbf{(b\times c)}$. From these two facts, you should be able to see that $\mathbf{d}$ must lie in the plane formed by the vectors $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$! (If you're not convinced, try it out: the first cross-product between $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ takes you out of the $\mathbf{bc}-$plane, and the second cross product (with $\mathbf{a}$) has to bring you back onto it, because we're in three dimensions!)

As a result, since $\mathbf{d}$ lies in the plane of the vectors $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$, it can therefore be written as a linear combination of them: $$\mathbf{d} = \alpha \, \mathbf{b} + \beta \, \mathbf{c},$$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars.

We now use the fact that $\mathbf{d}$ must be linear in $\mathbf{a}$,$\mathbf{b}$, and $\mathbf{c}$, and therefore all the terms on the right hand side must have only one power of each of these vectors respectively. Thus, $\alpha$ *must* be proportional to $(\mathbf{a\cdot c})$, since it has to be a scalar constructed from $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{c}$, and similarly $\beta$ must be proportional to $(\mathbf{a\cdot b})$. Thus, $$\mathbf{d} = A\, (\mathbf{a\cdot c}) \mathbf{b} + B\, (\mathbf{a\cdot b}) \mathbf{c},$$ where $A$ and $B$ are two absolute constants (dimensionless numbers) that are independent of the vectors.

Using the fact that $\mathbf{d}$ changes sign if $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are interchanged, you should trivially be able to show that $A=-B$, and so $$\mathbf{d} = A\, \Big( (\mathbf{a\cdot c}) \mathbf{b} - (\mathbf{a\cdot b}) \mathbf{c}\Big).$$ All that's left to do now is to determine $A$, which is easily done by taking a special case (since the above equation is valid for *all* vectors), so we could set $\mathbf{a} = \hat{\mathbf{x}}, \mathbf{b} = \hat{\mathbf{x}}, \mathbf{c} = \hat{\mathbf{y}},$ for example, and we'd see in this case that $A= 1$, and so $$\mathbf{a \times (b\times c)} = (\mathbf{a\cdot c}) \mathbf{b} - (\mathbf{a\cdot b}) \mathbf{c}$$

Comment: Given that this is a Physics EM question, I think this is much more likely what is being looked for since undergrad physics won't be covering Levi-Civita and this requires an intuitional understanding of vectors which is more valuable in Physics

Answer (score 3):

A more down-to-earth approach is to prove this identity in three-dimensional space by writing it down in terms of vector components: $\vec{a} = (a_x, a_y, a_z)$, etc.,  and using the expression for the vector product
$$
\vec{a}\times\vec{b} 
=
\left|
\begin{matrix}
\hat{e}_x & \hat{e}_y & \hat{e}_z \\
a_x & a_y & a_z \\
b_x & b_y & b_z
\end{matrix}
\right|
$$
It may seem a bit tedious, but it is straightforward and foolproof.

**Update**
In some corners this identity is called **Bee-Ay-Cee minus Cee-Ay-Bee**, which is a simple mnemonic rule for memorizing it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [the contraction identities of the Levi-Civita symbol.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions_2) I strongly encourage you to prove these identities yourself as well, I think you will find it worth the effort in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation of the axes does not affect the cross and dot products. Since the equation is obvious if  $\mathbf{b}  \times  \mathbf{c}$ is zero, we can assume that $\mathbf{b}  \times  \mathbf{c}$ is a nonzero multiple of $\mathbf{i}.$   Now, we can  assume that $\mathbf{b}=(0,r,0)$ and that $\mathbf{c}=(0,s,t),$ with both $r$ and $t$ nonzero. Thus,
$$\mathbf{a} \times (\mathbf{b}  \times  \mathbf{c})=rt(0,a_3,-a_2).$$ As observed in another answer, $\mathbf{a} \times (\mathbf{b}  \times  \mathbf{c})$ is linear combination of $\mathbf{b}$  and $\mathbf{c}.$ Thus, $\mathbf{a} \times (\mathbf{b}  \times  \mathbf{c})=$ $$rt(0,a_3,-a_2)=k_1\mathbf{b} +k_2\mathbf{c} =k_1(0,r,0)+k_2(0,s,t).$$ Clearly, $$k_2=-ra_2=-\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}.$$ From  $rta_3=k_1r+k_2t,$ we conclude that
$$k_1=sa_2+ta_3=\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{c}.$$ Observe that the  cross-product calculations above were extremely easy.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know when $\epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{kmn}$ is different from zero.  A basic property is that $\epsilon_{ijk} = \epsilon_{jki} = \epsilon_{kij} = -\epsilon_{ikj}$ (cyclical and anti-cyclical permutations of the indices).  So to make reasoning simpler, let's rewrite your product as $\epsilon_{kij} \epsilon_{kmn}$.  Note that this can only be non-zero if all indices $1,2,3$ appear exactly once in each term, and since $k$ appears in both this means that in all non-zero terms either $i=m$ and $j=n$ or $i=n$ and $j=m$.  In the first case both $\epsilon$s have the same indices and thus evaluate to the same value giving a product equal $+1$, in the second case they evaluate to the opposite value, and thus their product is $+1\times -1=-1$.  This can be summed up in the identity given in the accepted answer:$$ \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{kmn} = \delta_{im}\delta_{jn} - \delta_{in}\delta_{jm}. $$
The remainder is identifying the products that remain after simplifying via $a_i \equiv \delta_{ij} a_j$.